# Scannning site in ZAP, by Login

Tags: zap

I'm testing scan site with login credentials.

In normal, from terminal using this command
zap.sh -cmd -quickurl http://example.com

What is command for scan by login?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the command line options are limited so you cant use them for authenticated scans.
You will need to start ZAP as a daemon and control it via the API. We have various example scripts that do this.